# Have a problem with Python Crash Course, exercise 9-15

Tags: python

Exercise: You can use a loop to see how hard it might be to win the kind of lottery you just modeled. Make a list or tuple called my_ticket. Write a loop that keeps pulling numbers until your ticket wins. Print a message reporting how many times the loop had to run to give you a winning ticket.

I was doing this exercise and got the problem. 'Trials' appears just 50 per cent of time so my solution is not right. Could you help me with that?

```
from random import choice

lottery = [1, 2]

completed_lottery = []

my_ticket = [1]

trials = 0

def random_number():

    while True:

        if len(completed_lottery) != 1:
            number = choice(lottery)
            completed_lottery.append(number)
        else:
            break

while True:

    random_number()
    trials += 1
    
    if completed_lottery == my_ticket:
        print(f"Trials: {trials}")
        break
```

Comment: You have a list of two items [1,2] and a ticket with [1]. It's obvious that you have a 50% chance of winning here because you'll either draw 1 or 2 (assuming uniform distribution).

Comment: "'Trials' appears just 50 per cent": but that seems to actually correct. `my_ticket` only contains `[1]`, and your `completed_lottery` contains a number that is *randomly* picked from a list of `[1, 2`]. So you'd expect half of the time that `1` is picked, which results in "Trials" being printed; the other half of the time, the if statement comparison is False.

Answer (score 0):

You must reset `completed_lottery` (`completed_lottery = []`) or you'll have an infinite loop if the first trial is not successful.  For example:

```
while True:
    completed_lottery = []
    random_number()
    trials += 1
    
    if completed_lottery == my_ticket:
        print(f"Trials: {trials}")
        break
```